# Facebook Connect vs Twitter Anywhere vs OpenID for third-party login/registration system?

Tags: facebook, openid, twitter

We want to streamline the user registration and login process.  The goal is to reduce the time and effort for users to register and login to our site.

At the same time, we don't want to overwhelm users with choices.  We don't like how some web sites present registration/login options via multiple channels (e.g., Facebook, Twitter).

What are the pros/cons of each of these systems?  Which do you use, and what are your main gripes?

Comment: an article mentioning pros/cons of facebook connect & openid: http://rww.readwriteweb.netdna-cdn.com/archives/facebook_connect_vs_open_id.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes, it does all depend on your user audience.

In any case, I would say that Facebook Connect is probably your best bet due to the sheer number of people using Facebook. Still, as far as I've noticed, it's not really "professional" websites that use Facebook Connect, mostly forums and unofficial (but popular) news blogs.

Many "professional" websites (catering to... well, professionals) will use a normal Register/Login rather than Twitter, Facebook, or OpenID. Still, a professional website would likely need a more professional solution, so I would suggest OpenID, which also supports websites such as Yahoo! Mail and developer communities (such as Stack Overflow!). You can see the full list of sites [here](https://www.myopenid.com/directory).

In all honesty, I don't really think that using a Twitter login would be very efficient. Think of it this way: for one, I've noticed (but I could be wrong) that Twitter is mainly used by the small hobbyist or the people who use it to give updates on things they're doing or making (and sometimes just the people who want to be in on the times). So unless your website is aimed at these type of people, it wouldn't really be useful. On top of that, I don't know of many people who particularly like it, partially because of its over-popularity. Still, it could be the same way with Facebook, but this is all subjective, so if you really want to pick Twitter, go for it.

Anyway, that's my take on things. I don't personally use these systems on websites I've built, but I know how they work.

For one, when you log in using any of these for the first time, they take the user to a new page or open a popup window asking them to confirm if they want to connect their [Whatever] account to your [Website Name]. After that, it's a bit easier to use just because they don't have to keep repeating the process unless they disallow your website on their service.

With OpenID, you have to log in to your OpenID-enabled webpage using **http://myusername.myopenid.com/** or **myusername.myopenid.com**. If they don't choose to remember their password, this can become a bit tedious to type in every time.

With Facebook Connect, it usually automatically connects all of their information to the website, including full name and profile picture (meaning that if they have a profile picture of that snazzy tattoo on their inner thigh, other users will be able to see that).

Finally, as far as I can see, Twitter doesn't do much other than connect whatever name you had on your profile page (if it's "John Doe" or "Weiner Schnitzel", it'll show on your website) and your profile picture, just like Facebook.

To finish up, those are pretty much all the pros and cons that I can tell about the services. Good luck!

Comment: -1 for the *not professional* paragraph! just check the [facebook showcase](http://developers.facebook.com/showcase/)

Comment: @ifaour Hmm, interesting. I guess I was wrong! Still, it's all subjective, so he can pick what he likes. Thanks for the heads-up, though!

Answer (score 8):

**Offer all of them, don't take the time to ask "why?".**
It's always worth it to get users on board.

Answer (score 7):

The biggest (IMO) pro is that you are no longer storing passwords in your db. Leveraging one of those other site's authentication service relieves you of this. It doesn't relieve you of having a secure design. I'm also not sure that your average end user really cares. If your service is highly aligned with one of those services, maybe. However, if you are not targetting those end-users, then probably not.

Rob Conery did a recent write up of his experience with OpenId. This might be a good read:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/thoughts/open-id-is-a-party-that-happened

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: The author seems to have been disappointed with OpenID (for whatever reason) and his disappointment speaks instead of himself.

Answer (score 2):

What is your target group?

- If you want that many normal people uses your application than use Facebook.
- If there are many coder / blogger / internet junkies than use Twitter.
- If you have a lot of open source guys than OpenID will do the job.

Comment: +1, but I would change/edit the second point to "Use Twitter *or OpenID* " since people mentioned in this point are most likely familiar with OpenID

Answer (score 1):

If i'm is not wrong, previously there is a website providing kinda service about providing login platform to allow user connect to your site. Of course it is not free and i was abandon it because of high annual fees and mind change after research being done.

While you using their service to growing your business or website, you can save their time it's true. but honestly, will they really care on how long time taken to connect their facebook with your website either register as a new member in your website. While you can give confidence to you client, they do. they willing to spent few minute to fill up simple information to make an account for them self if they felt they worth to spent the minute to get service from your website.

Totally agreed to what rcravens said, if they connect through third party website, means you are gonna giving you user information to that website. For example, to archive FACEBOOK CONNECT you will need to create an application for them to trust them you only can get authority to access. while they  accept and login to your site, it is good for FREE advertise because while they connect, can use their account as medium to post your information to public. **BUT** mostly site will sell their information gather or share them in any way to some organization who need them for decision. 
**My point is, how many people using your site and mostly who is using, what characteristic of your site user and so on... everything is no more under your control !!!**

Perhaps, you may use it but what if their service shut down few hour for maintainance...

Comment: there is a website providing most famous login platform e.g yahoo, google and facebook or twitter, they do combine them and provide as a service to allow you use them all in you site. please share it if you know because i was forgotten what it is while i felt no longer need it XD Thank you ~

Comment: That is !!! RPX ~ No wonder i can't found it because they waschange the name =.= Thankx to @Nader =D

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using something like RPXNow (https://rpxnow.com/) or Gigya (http://www.gigya.com/) as an intermediary to the various authentication providers.  Facebook and Twitter are notorious for always changing their APIs.  It is a pain to keep up with them.  These services give you a simple abstraction layer, so that you don't need to change anything on your end when the providers change their APIs.

Answer (score 0):

i like facebook but..

- facebook is block in some country.
- open id is not famous.
- twitter is famous and simple.

so use twitter is the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenID as it is a standard that is also integrated into many Mail Accounts, like Google or Yahoo. You never know how long Facebook will stay around and therefore it's better to have something people just don't throw away (there Mail address). If you make a nice selection screen (e.g. stackoverflow), the people don't even know that they're using OpenID. If you just want to get authorized Comments, picture uploads for twitter or fb, a game connected with social features don't use it.

Facebook Connect is very usable for one time comments or stuff like this. If you want to store your own data about the user (e.g. blog service, saas), not dependend on "social networks" don't use it.

Twitter Login makes only sense if you connect your service with Twitter, otherwise forget about it.

I would use a hidden OpenID approach.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is great for keeping tabs on family and friends. Beyond that I, personally, wouldn't use it in support of any other app. It's just not bullet-proof enough from a security/malware standpoint. There is too great a chance someone could have issues of that sort with Facebook and attribute it to your site, whether reasonably so or not.

I like OpenID. Not thrilled with the notion of hitching my wagon to any of the social networking sites/services at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a technical or commercial question?

The answer to my mind is it depends what you want to do with the data.

If you just want to provide a service to a broad list of people then the answer has to be to gun for openness, not proprietary - particularly since the open standard is supported elsewhere, Gmail, Yahoo et al.

However, if you want to demographically profile that database at some point to offer targeted services, then you need to understand the questions you're likely to require answered and whether a third party method is going to enable that or not.